# Библиотека pygame, def и основной цикл, Python!

Tags: python, pygame, while

Короче, у меня есть небольшая проблема с моей игрой, (Код ниже!). Вобщем я создал функцию, пробовал в цикле отображать(sc.blit), и в самой функиции всё равно ошибка!!!
Помогите пожалуйста!

```
import pygame as pg 
import random
from random import randint
pg.init()


RES = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 480, 850
_TITLE = 'In the Wild Forest'

sc = pg.display.set_mode(RES)
pg.display.set_caption(_TITLE)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

_FPS = 30

clock = pg.time.Clock()

_heal = 100
_damage = 5
_money = 0

font = pg.font.SysFont('Calibri', 45)

clock = pg.time.Clock()

_game_play = True

def blujd():
    global _money
    _shans = randint(1, 25)
    _blujdtext = font.render('Блуждаю...', 5, WHITE)
    if yslovie <= 50:
        while True:
            sc.blit(_blujdtext, (145,220))
            pg.display.update()
            clock.tick(_FPS)
    if _shans <= 23:
        _nahodka = font.render('Ничего не нашёл!', 5, WHITE)
    else: 
        _gold = randint(1,3)
        _money += _gold
        _nahodka = font.render('Монет найдено: ' + str(_gold), 5, WHITE)
    global _game_play
    _game_play = False


while True:
    sc.fill(BLACK)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            quit()
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                _game_play = True

    while _game_play:
        yslovie = randint(1, 50)
        if yslovie <= 50:
            blujd()

    

    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(_FPS)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

функция `blujd` у вас не знает что такое `yslovie`, вам придется отсылать его как аргумент в `blujd` или определять его в самой этой функции, то есть:

```
def blujd():
    yslovie = randint(1, 50)
    if yslovie <= 50:

        global _money
        _shans = randint(1, 25)
        _blujdtext = font.render('Блуждаю...', 5, WHITE)
        if yslovie <= 50:
            while True:
                sc.blit(_blujdtext, (145,220))
                pg.display.update()
                clock.tick(_FPS)
        if _shans <= 23:
            _nahodka = font.render('Ничего не нашёл!', 5, WHITE)
        else: 
            _gold = randint(1,3)
            _money += _gold
            _nahodka = font.render('Монет найдено: ' + str(_gold), 5, WHITE)
        global _game_play
        _game_play = False
```

также следует заметить, что функция `blujd` у вас вызывается только если выполняется условие `if yslovie <= 50:`, следовательно, вам не надо делать повторную проверку этого утверждения в функции `blujd`, то есть:

```
def blujd():
    global _money
    _shans = randint(1, 25)
    _blujdtext = font.render('Блуждаю...', 5, WHITE)
    while True:
    sc.blit(_blujdtext, (145,220))
    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(_FPS)
    if _shans <= 23:
        _nahodka = font.render('Ничего не нашёл!', 5, WHITE)
    else: 
        _gold = randint(1,3)
        _money += _gold
        _nahodka = font.render('Монет найдено: ' + str(_gold), 5, WHITE)
    global _game_play
    _game_play = False
```

Comment: спасибо большое